# Unable to position a button to the bottom of screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-widget

Im trying to align two buttons ("Reset" and "Apply") at the bottom but it always aligns itself to the top of the screen

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/form_bg">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/strp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <com.widget.AppButton
                android:id="@+id/country_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_config"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Country"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <com.widget.AppButton
                android:id="@+id/domain_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_config"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="Domain"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <com.widget.AppButton
                android:id="@+id/unit_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_config"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Unit"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/white_divider" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/black_divider" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/strp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.widget.AppButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/btn"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <com.widget.AppButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Apply"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/btn"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>`
```

I have of-course set layout_alignParentBottom to true but still the problem persists

Comment: Remove `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/strp"` and set height to `wrap_content`.

Comment: try removing `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/strp"`

Comment: use LinearLayout instead

Comment: can you please remove android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/strp" and replace it with android:layout_alignBottom="@id/strp" I believe @+id is used when you are decalring the id for the first time and when you re-use the existing id you wont put + :) just give a try once :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your last `LinearLayout` by

- remove `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/strp"`
- change `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

So the code should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/form_bg">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/strp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <com.widget.AppButton
                android:id="@+id/country_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_config"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Country"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <com.widget.AppButton
                android:id="@+id/domain_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_config"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="Domain"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <com.widget.AppButton
                android:id="@+id/unit_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_config"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Unit"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/white_divider" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/black_divider" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.widget.AppButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/btn"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <com.widget.AppButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Apply"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/btn"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to, change your **Relativelayout to Linearlayout** because you dont need to give extra attributes using that and remove invalid params from that layout file  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/form_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/strp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <com.widget.AppButton
                android:id="@+id/country_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_config"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Country"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <com.widget.AppButton
                android:id="@+id/domain_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_config"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="Domain"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <com.widget.AppButton
                android:id="@+id/unit_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_config"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Unit"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/white_divider" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/black_divider" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.widget.AppButton
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.widget.AppButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Apply"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_alignBottom=" "` Works better when inside a Relative layout, try using it inside of a Relative Layout. Also use the `android:layout_alignBottom=" "` on the buttons instead of on the layout.

```
<RelativeLayout // Changed it to RL
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" // Removed AlignBottom
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.widget.AppButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="true" // this one
        android:text="Reset"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.widget.AppButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="true" // This one
        android:text="Apply"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```